# Total sum from current ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I get nothing in return and, can anyone see the simple ting that I am missing?

```
SELECT SUM(Amount * InPrice) AS TotalItemsOrdered
FROM tblMaterial
WHERE [tblMaterial].[OwnerId] = [tblTask].[Id]
```

Do I need to do something different to get a result?

Hope for a simple answer....yes I am new at this :)

Comment: how should we know what's in your DB? We don't know content of tblMaterial

Comment: You are selecting from `tblMaterial` and not from `tblTask`, so `[tblTask].[Id]` should be unknown. You get an error.

Comment: Please join your tables tblMaterial and tblTask

Comment: FROM tblMaterial, tblTask
but a JOIN would be better.

There's also a semantic issue: TotalItemsOrdered is not really what you're doing, because sum(amount * inprice) is probably TotalSumOrdered.

Comment: He can use where but in way @HerbertVan-Vliet wrote

Comment: How do I join? (Sorry)

Answer (score 0):

You need either select from two tables or do JOIN

select option:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount * InPrice) AS TotalItemsOrdered
FROM [tblMaterial], [tblTask]
WHERE [tblMaterial].[OwnerId] = [tblTask].[Id]
```

join option:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount * InPrice) AS TotalItemsOrdered
FROM [tblMaterial]
INNER JOIN [tblTask] ON [tblMaterial].[OwnerId] = [tblTask].[Id]
```

You may also need to prefix columns in SUM function with table name if they occur in both tables.

Here you can read more about SQL joins:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx
- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1667/sql-server-join-example/

Comment: Thanks, all your answer works but I get the total sum och everything in hole database. I thougt I get the Sum from the current ID when I exe in the program...I think this is to tugh for me. But thanks everyone!

Comment: @Kristoffer , if you want a sum per OwnerId ? , you can put `GROUP BY tblMaterial.OwnerId`

Answer (score 0):

The tblTask is missing from your select.

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount * InPrice) AS TotalItemsOrdered
FROM tblMaterial, tblTask
WHERE tblMaterial.OwnerId = tblTask.Id
```

Or use a join:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount * InPrice) AS TotalItemsOrdered
FROM tblMaterial
INNER JOIN tblTask 
ON tblMaterial.OwnerId = tblTask.Id
```

Comment: how is this diffrent from my answer?

Comment: Thanks, all your answer works but I get the total sum och everything in hole database. I thougt I get the Sum from the current ID when I exe in the program...I think this is to tugh for me. But thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Just put `GROUP BY` if you want to `SUM` per `ID`

```
SELECT tblMaterial.OwnerId
    , SUM(Amount * InPrice) AS TotalItemsOrdered
FROM tblMaterial INNER JOIN tblTask ON tblMaterial.OwnerId = tblTask.Id
GROUP BY tblMaterial.OwnerId
```